# Установить значение в объекте

Tags: ооп, php

Добрый день.

Допустим, у нас существует объект:

```
$var = object(Taxonomies)#73 (12) {
  ["_new":"CActiveRecord":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["_attributes":"CActiveRecord":private]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "testName"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(9) "testSlug"
    ["code"]=>
    string(9) "testCode"
    ["count"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  ["_related":"CActiveRecord":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_c":"CActiveRecord":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_pk":"CActiveRecord":private]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["_alias":"CActiveRecord":private]=>
  string(1) "t"
  ["_errors":"CModel":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_validators":"CModel":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_scenario":"CModel":private]=>
  string(6) "update"
  ["_e":"CComponent":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_m":"CComponent":private]=>
  NULL
}
```

**Вопрос**: каким образом можно преобразовать его в:

```
$var = object(Taxonomies)#73 (12) {
  ["_new":"CActiveRecord":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["_attributes":"CActiveRecord":private]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "testName"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(9) "testSlug"
    ["code"]=>
    string(9) "testCode"
    ["count"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["custom"]=>
    string(1) "10"
  }
  ["_related":"CActiveRecord":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_c":"CActiveRecord":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_pk":"CActiveRecord":private]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["_alias":"CActiveRecord":private]=>
  string(1) "t"
  ["_errors":"CModel":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_validators":"CModel":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_scenario":"CModel":private]=>
  string(6) "update"
  ["_e":"CComponent":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_m":"CComponent":private]=>
  NULL
}
```

То есть каким образом можно установить в массиве `_attributes` новое значение?

Пытался таким образом:

```
$var->_attributes->custom = '10';
```

и таким (через функцию yii):

```
$var->setAttribute('custom', '10');
```

В первом случае ошибка, во втором - custom добавляется в начало объекта, то есть перед `_new`, а не в `_attributes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем? Это все внутренние свойства, которые вам никогда не нужно трогать руками.

**Обновление**

Пара решений:

- просто объявите свойство у объекта, насколько помню, оно автоматом появится в `attributes`
- если я неправ с первым пунктом, попробуйте хакнуть `attributeNames`:

  ```
  public function attributeNames()
  {
       $names = parent::attributeNames();
       $names[] = 'custom';
       return $names;
  }
  ```

99%, что все компоненты тем или иным способом вытягивают информацию через `attributeNames`.

Comment: Необходимо было добиться того, чтобы значение появилось в списке атрибутов. То есть, допустим, когда виджет CDetailView запрашивает список атрибутов, чтобы вместе с остальными был дополнительный атрибут, которого не существует как колонки в таблице БД. Но не удалось найти качественное решение, поэтому устанавливаю дополнительный атрибут напрямую, при работе с виджетом.

Comment: Второй вариант сработал, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте

```
$var->custom = '10';
```